# Meaning of “battery” in “same substantial battery of six physical tests”

Tags: word-meaning

Does "battery" here mean "group"?  Bing dictionary gives the definition "a group of similar things". I am not sure the definition fits.

> The research, overseen by gerontologist Taina Rantanen of the University of Jyväskylä, compares adults born in 1910 and 1914 with those born roughly 30 years later. The two age groups were assessed in 1989 and 1990 and in 2017 and 2018, respectively. The beauty of this work is that both birth cohorts were examined in person at age 75 and again at 80 with the **same substantial battery of six physical tests** and five measures of cognition. Most cohort studies look at a narrower range of measures, and many of them rely on self-assessments.

Source: Scientific American   [Is 70 Really the New 60?](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/is-70-really-the-new-60/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *battery*, as in the thing that powers electrical devices, is actually short for *a battery of cells*, because it can be several cells packaged together as a single unit. *Battery* really describes a group of (usually similar) things that are meant to operate together, as a whole.

So *a battery of tests* implies a group of tests, taken together, that form some kind of cohesive whole. Because you do them all together, it gives a sense that they're all important and testing different things, and you have to complete all of them to build the final result.

Comment: A battery of cells was so-named because a battery of guns (or cannons in those days) was a group or collection of guns in one place. Some say the term was first used by Benjamin Franklin when he joined a number of Leyden jars together and called the result a 'battery'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the same set of tests and measures. This particular set (battery) is **substantial**ly bigger than used with other cohorts.

Note that 'battery of tests' is a common phrase in the fields of psychology and medicine.

> Examples from the Corpus 
>  **a battery of something** 
> • a battery of medical
> and psychological tests 
> ... 
> • All the children underwent a battery of tests at regular intervals. 
> • She was airlifted to Childrens Hospital, where she underwent a battery of tests. 
> https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-battery-of-something